# Prevent NGINX-ingress from responding to public IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

What's the process for either preventing NGINX from responding to the Public IP, or to get it to redirect to somewhere else - like another URL.

I'm a little stumped as I can't seem to find much in the way of documentation anywhere for this situation. We're using cert-manager too.

Essentially a PEN Test has failed because the public IP is responding with an NGINX/ k8s self-signed cert. We don't want or need that!

Comment: Just configure cert-manager to use lets-encrypt 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to solve this; easy for HTTP and difficult for HTTPS. The main problem is to issue a certificate for an IP address, not any issuer does that (letsencrypt for example doesn't), so you have to find one or try whichever you use now.

To handle unknown hosts (like an IP address) you can create an ingress object without `host` field in rules. This will make the created ingress work as 'default' or 'fallback' rule, thus it will be used when there is no better match by `Host` header (any ingress *with* `host` in rules).

To create an ingress object you need a service and here's how you can create a dummy service without endpoints:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dummy-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
```

Next, the ingress for it:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: default-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress_class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      # Nginx will place this in server block

      # You can redirect all requests somewhere:
      return 301 https://example.com/;
      # or just:
      #return 403;
spec:
  rules:
    # This rule has no 'host' field and because of that
    # NGINX won't include 'server_name' directive in
    # vhost configuration. What this means is that this
    # ingress rule will be used only if the request
    # comes with 'Host' header for which there is no
    # specific rule (IP-address for example).
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              servicePort: 80
              serviceName: dummy-service
```

At this point you've got redirect (or 403) working for HTTP and HTTPS, although the latter with a dummy certificate. If you managed to issue a certificate for your IP addresses and save it as a secret, the next thing is to make NGINX to use it instead of its default dummy certificate. For that you need to modify ingress controller deployment by adding `--default-ssl-certificate` argument:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: controller
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            # use 'namespace/secret_name' as the value for the argument
            - --default-ssl-certificate=default/ip-cert-secret
```

Now NGINX will respond to IP addresses with a valid certificate.

**Bonus**: if you have a cert-manager `Issuer` or `ClusterIssuer` that can issue a certificate for IP address (like self-signed one), you can request a certificate with the following manifest:

```yaml
#apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1beta1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ip-cert
spec:
  secretName: ip-cert-secret
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  isCA: false
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    encoding: PKCS1
    size: 2048
  usages:
    - server auth
    - client auth
  commonName: Dummy
  ipAddresses:
  - 10.1.1.13 # fill the list
  issuerRef:
    name: # insert issuer name
    kind: # Issuer or ClusterIssuer 
    group: cert-manager.io
```